# Xcode 4.1 not downloading - Lion

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, xcode

I am trying to download Xcode 4.1 from the Mac App Store (I am on Lion, and I have Xcode 3 installed). The problem is that the download bar barely moved, and after being stuck there for an hour it reset to 0%.

Comment: did you try downloading any other apps? do they work?

Comment: Yes, other apps download fine.

Comment: it could be paused, try clicking on it to resume

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the partial download by searching for Install in spotlight, then return to the purchased section and re-download the installer.

A reboot will ensure it's not paused or some temporary error has caused the slowness.

Answer (score 1):

If the App Store download doesn't work, you could download (for free) the Xcode dmg directly from [Downloads for Apple Developers](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).